# File format for meta data of data set

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, data-mining, file-format, feature-engineering

I would like to know and compare as many file formats as possible, which can store meta data of features, attributes, or fields

The meta data of attributes may be:

- storage type: String, numeric, integer, datetime, etc
- scale type: Nominal, Ordinal, Interval, Ratio, etc
- format of date time to parse: "YYYY-mm-dd_HH:MM:SS", etc

For example, ARFF and SAV can have meta data of attributes

- Text:

  - [ARFF of Weka](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/arff.html)
- Binary

  - [SAV, ZSAV of SPSS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_23.0.0/spss/base/savedatatypes.html)

I would very appreciate if you let me know other data formats so that I can compare them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to search the internet some more. You missed a number of obvious choices. Beginning with "abused" formats such as Python pickles, to unspecific formats such as JSON and YAML, to "big data" formats such as Apache Arrow, to scientific formats such as HDF 4 and HDF 5.